# canvas.getClipBounds().left is 0 always while zooming canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas

After zooming Canvas the value of

canvas.getClipBounds().left is always 0

canvas.getClipBounds().top is always 0

These value never changes while zooming.Is there any wrong implementation?

```
Rect clipBounds = new Rect();
int canvasLeft;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    canvas.save();

    canvasLeft = canvas.getClipBounds().left;

    if(scaleGestureDetector.isInProgress()){
        scaleGestureFocusX = this.scaleGestureDetector.getFocusX();
        scaleGestureFocusY = this.scaleGestureDetector.getFocusY();
        canvas.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor, scaleGestureFocusX, scaleGestureFocusY);
    }
    else{

        canvas.scale(this.scaleFactor, this.scaleFactor, scaleGestureFocusX, scaleGestureFocusY);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);       
    canvas.restore();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling canvas.getClipBounds().left after canvas.save(). That's why every time it **returns 0** cause after newly generated canvas clip bound is always 0.

Solution :  Call **canvas.getClipBounds().left** first then call **canvas.save()**.